# How to pass an extra property to a usercontrol which is inside DataTemplate, in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have an Itemscontrol in my xaml, and I am calling a user control in the DateTemplate of ItemsControl like following

> ```
>     <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0">
>         <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsStackPanel">
>             <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
>                 <DataTemplate>
>                     <controls:UserItem Margin="0, 5, 0, 3"></controls:UserItem>
>                 </DataTemplate>
>             </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
>         </ItemsControl>
>     </ScrollViewer>
> ```

I already assign a list to ItemsControl.

> ```
>     this.itemsStackPanel.ItemsSource = usersList;
> ```

and now I want to pass something extra property to my user control,  which is inside DataTemplate, something like following, how do I do that?

> ```
>     <controls:UserItem Margin="0, 5, 0, 3" CurrentColumnInfo={Binding oColumnInfo}></controls:UserItem>
> ```

the *oColumnInfo* object is kept in the codebehind. how do I pass that to each user item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next practice (it likes ria controls):

> First, create object provider for your oColumnInfo:

public class ObjProvider : Control
{
public object Object { get; set; }
}

> Second, create instance of ObjProvider in your markup:

< !-Extra property provider-->

< p:ObjProvider x:Name="provider" Width="0" Height="0"/>

> Third, in your item template:

< controls:UserItem Margin="0, 5, 0, 3" CurrentColumnInfo={Binding ElementName=provider, Path=Object} />

> Fourth, in code behind

provider.Object = oColumnInfo;

That's it

> The other way (not so good) is:
>
> First, in your item template

< controls:UserItem Margin="0, 5, 0, 3" CurrentColumnInfo={Binding Source={StaticResource oColumnInfo} />

> Second, in code behind:
>
> this.Resources.Add("oColumnInfo", oColumnInfo);
>
> //NOTE!!!: you must do it in constructor >before InitializeComponent(), that's why this way is not so flexible
> and setting resource from the code behind and binding to it in markup isn't a good practice

Comment: thanks, your first solution works. I was trying to use the second method, but it was not working, and now you told that I must include the resource in the constructor, which is not possible in my case, thanks anyways. You were helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

oColumnInfo should be part of your userList, if you want to bind using `{Binding Path=oColumnInfo}`

Comment: any better solution? I do not want to keep oColumnInfo inside userList, because userList is already of oColumnInfo. it will become circular dependency then.

Comment: Not sure of your object structure, you can try IValueConverter
and pass the corresponding oColumnInfo object based on any property of your usersList.